# What does Ubuntu iso "desktop image " mean?

Tags: installation, live-cd, cd-image

I see [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/) the expression" desktop image" in the sense that it "allows you to try Ubuntu without changing your computer at all, and at your option to install it permanently later"

Is this just about the fact that it is a "live cd" and provides the "try ubuntu" option, or is it about something else?

Comment: What else could it be? Here Desktop includes all **stand alone** platforms such as desktops, laptops, palmtops, fingertops, etc. The "image" refers to the iso file format that allows an image of a CD/DVD to be stored, copied, transferred etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading it, I assume "desktop" means the Desktop Computer or PC. The other version available is the Server edition, which is without GUI (as I understand after visiting this site for two months).

It IS a Live CD but of the desktop version.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the "desktop image" is just the ISO for the Ubuntu live CD. That is, the CD with the *Install Ubuntu* and *Try Ubuntu* options.